# *ngif not binding to variable on page

Tags: angular

I'm testing out a new menu structure and having issues binding it using *ngif for some reason.

Stats:
Angular 7
Chrome Browser

The menu itself has buttons and is working fine - it's coded as such on the HTML:

```
   <p-tabMenu [model]="items" [activeItem]="items[0]"></p-tabMenu>
```

Further down the page I'm starting to build out what will be an array selection (just for testing purposes) of if statements, eventually will be bound to an object but for testing:

```
  <p *ngif="activeItem =='0'" ><app-dashboard></app-dashboard></p>
```

I've played around with different options but am stuck. I'm really just trying to evaluate if the activeItem is item 0 in the array of items that it's true show the app, else skip.

Comment: change *ngif to *ngIf

Answer (score 2):

> I'm really just trying to evaluate if the activeItem is item 0 in the array of items that it's true show the app, else skip

You've bind `activeItem` to the first element of the array `items` here:

```
<p-tabMenu [model]="items" [activeItem]="items[0]"></p-tabMenu>
```

So the right way to check for this condition is (also use `*ngIf` not `*ngif`):

```
<p *ngIf="activeItem == items[0]">
  <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
</p>
```

Comment: Sometimes it's always the small things that catch you :-) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have typo in *ngif proper value is *ngIf.

you can very well find exception on developer tools console